# How to add indexes for MongoDB collection?

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

In PhalconPHP, I'd like to add indexes to a collection, let's say for the purpose of preventing duplicated email for instance.

In MongoDB I understand we can use ensureIndex, but where to use this in Phalcon?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: I'd think you'd need to use the default driver for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.ensureindex.php

Comment: I prefer to do it through Phalcon, but I'd go for that as a last resort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not used PhalconPHP and neither I can understand a reason to create indexes from an application level (why not to create them in mongoconsole), but here is how I would do this in [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.ensureindex.php).

Suppose I have a collection `users` and I want to create unique index for `email` field;

```
$coll = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');
$coll->ensureIndex(array(
   "email" => 1
), array(
   "unique" => 1,
   "dropDups" => 1
));
```

Be careful - this will remove all duplicate values in your collection and you do not know which one will be counted as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Salvador, I'd like to make things automated.

Comment: How would you get the $db variable in Phalcon? You wouldn't use the PHP way again, right?

Comment: @Milad as I told, I have no idea what is Phalcon and how to use it. This is purely PHP script with no Phalcon part.